# How to show the database table names in a table format in html page

Tags: html, python-3.x

The HTML page to display all table names from data base:

### index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
{%for row in results%}

        <table>
      <tr>
         <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
{%endfor%}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### It outputs :

```
table1
table2
.
.
.
```

### Expected output:

I want to show 3 columns 1)assign numbers to each table name automatically from 1 and so on 2) one table name in one row (data from database) 3) Some common text to all rows
as:

```
-------------------------------------------
| SNO | Tables in Database | Database Name|
-------------------------------------------
|  1  |       table1       |   CONFIG     |
|  2  |       table2       |   CONFIG     |
|  3  |       table3       |   CONFIG     |
-------------------------------------------
```

### I tried adding numbers to each row :

```
<table border="1">
```

and in index.css I tried this , also added the css path in my html:

```
table
{
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr > td:first-child
{
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before
{
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

but this result as:

```
-------------
|1 | table1 |
--------------
|1 | table2 |
-------------
|1 | table3 |
-------------
```

How can add a column DATABASE NAME and having one default value for all columns as shown in above expected one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add thead and tbody.
2. have only TRs in your loop `{%for row in results%}<tr><td></td><td>{{ row[0] }}</td><td></td></tr>{%endfor%}`
3. add content

Update: 
[python database name from cursor](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+cursor+database+name+site:stackoverflow.com)

```css
table {
  counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tbody tr>td:first-child {
  counter-increment: rowNumber;
  text-align:center;
}

table tr td:first-child::before {
  content: counter(rowNumber);
  min-width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

table tbody tr>td:last-child::before {
  content: 'CONFIG'
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SNO</th>
      <th>Tables in Database</th>
      <th>Database Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {%for row in results%}
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  {%endfor%}
</table>
```

assuming CONFIG is a constant.

Otherwise set it in the loop:  `<td>{{cr.dbname}}</td>`
 or whereever

Comment: Here the values for 'Tables in Database' column are fetched from database and if I write as above there creates a new table for every table name and SNO is 1 everytime, should I have to change the python code for this?

Comment: I am missing database names but the other two works fine

Comment: That would be a python issue

Comment: yeah but SNO works fine, so I'm thinking of why DATABASE NAME column which is not from python

Comment: table tbody tr>td:last-child::before {
  content: 'CONFIG'
}   any changes to this?

Comment: You tell me. I only see what you posted. If you need to have the database name in there, you can change that to <td>{{row[1]}}</td> instead of the CSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198469/discussion-between-codenewbie-and-mplungjan).